# Entity Framework - Union causes "Unable to create a constant value of type.."

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

To select all `Scheduling`s which are active, I have the following code:

```
var allSchedulesOnALine = CurrentUser.Lines.SelectMany(o => o.Scheduling).Where(o => o.Active);
var allSchedulesUnscheduled = Entities.SchedulingSet
    .Where(o => o.Line == null && o.Site.Id == CurrentUser.Site.Id &&
           o.Factory == CurrentUser.Factory && o.Active);

IEnumerable<Scheduling> allSchedules = allSchedulesUnscheduled.Union(allSchedulesOnALine);
foreach(Scheduling schedule in allSchedules.OrderBy(o => o.Ordering))
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

*(`Factory` is an `int`)*

When I run this code, I get this cryptic error on the `foreach` line:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Strangely enough, I can enumerate both `allSchedulesOnALine` and `allSchedulesUnscheduled` separately.  Even stranger, if I reorder the union:

```
IEnumerable<Scheduling> allSchedules = allSchedulesOnALine.Union(allSchedulesUnscheduled);
```

It works fine!

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?  Am I missing something crucial, or is this a bug?

*I should mention I am using Entity Framework 3.5.  EF4 is not an option for us currently - it is beyond my control :\*

Comment: I believe the error message indicates that EF can't translate your union statement to SQL, but I'm not sure why. Is it possible that `CurrentUser.Lines.SelectMany(o => o.Scheduling).Where(o => o.Active)` is not using deferred execution? In that case, it might explain why you can use it ordered one direction but not the other -- one is running in memory, the other is trying to run completely in SQL. Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're calling two different methods with your "reordering".

You don't show the types of `allSchedulesOnALine` or `allSchedulesUnscheduled`, but I'm betting `allSchedulesOnALine` is of type `IEnumerable<Schedule>` and `allSchedulesUnscheduled` is of type `IQueryable<Schedule>`.

So when you call [Queryable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049.aspx), you're asking the EF to translate the expression into SQL. But the *argument* you pass is of type `IEnumerable<Schedule>`, and it can't translate that into a query.

On the other hand, when you call [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx), you're asking LINQ to Objects to do the whole thing in memory, which works fine, albeit perhaps slower.

So the reason the behavior is different is that you're calling two completely different methods, which do different things, but happen to have the same name. No, it's not a bug.

Comment: This must be the dozen-th time you've helped me with an EF problem here, including, I think, this exact problem before (ugh).  Thanks again, Craig!