# Entity Framework, unable to create a constant value of type 'XX'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method that returns viewmodel as defined below:

```
if (studentId != null)
{
    var eduRec = (_context.EducationalRecords.Where(x => x.StudentId == studentId)).ToList();
    var guarnator = (_context.NextOfKinGuarantors.Where(x => x.StudentId == studentId)).ToList();

    model = (from stud in _context.Students
             join lga in _context.LocalGovts
                 on stud.LocalGovtId equals lga.LocalGovtId
             join st in _context.States
                 on lga.StateId equals st.StateId
             join acada in _context.AcademicRecords
                 on stud.StudentId equals acada.StudentId
             join dept in _context.Departments
                 on acada.DepartmentId equals dept.DepartmentId
             join faculty in _context.Falculties
                 on dept.FalcultyId equals faculty.FalcultyId
             join prg in _context.Programmes
                 on acada.ProgrammeId equals prg.ProgrammeId
             join lvl in _context.Levels
                 on acada.LevelId equals lvl.LevelId
             where acada.IsCurrentRecord == true && stud.StudentId == studentId
             select new StudentProfileViewModel()
             {
                 ContactAddress = stud.ContactAddress,
                 Department = dept.Name,
                 Disability = stud.Disability,
                 Othernames = stud.Othernames,
                 FirstName = stud.FirstName,
                 Surname = stud.Surname,
                 Programme = prg.Name,
                 RegistrationNumber = stud.RegistrationNumber,
                 Dob = stud.Dob,
                 EducationalRecords = eduRec,
                 Email = stud.Email,
                 Faculty = faculty.Name,
                 Gender = stud.Gender,
                 HomeAddress = stud.HomeAddress,
                 Level = lvl.Name,
                 LocalGoverment = lga.Name,
                 MaritalStatus = stud.MaritalStatus,
                 Phone = stud.Phone,
                 Religion = stud.Religion,
                 StateName = st.Name,
                 NextOfKinGuarantors = guarnator
             }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When I run the application I got this error message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Portal.Models.EducationalRecord'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

The definition of `EducationalRecords` is a list.

Comment: I'd create `StudentProfileViewModel` and **then** add items to `EducationalRecords` property (which is a list). Simply EF can't convert a list into a valid expression (_"...only primitive types or enumeration types are supported..."_).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create a constant value of type (type) Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220867/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-type-only-primitive-types-such-as)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ statement has to be translatable into a valid SQL query, so you have to be careful what you're calling. For instance, if you try to call some random method you wrote in C#, that probably won't translate to valid SQL, so you'll get an error.

In your case, it's complaining about trying to populate `EducationalRecords` using a separate LINQ statement, which apparently it cannot translate into a single SQL statement.

Remove this line from your LINQ statement:

```
EducationalRecords = eduRec,
```

Get the `EducationalRecords` separately, after you populate `model`:

```
if (model != null)
   model.EducationalRecords =
      _context.EducationalRecords.Where(x => x.StudentId == studentId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Grant has already dealt with the problem in the code you posted, but there's a better solution to the entire problem.  Use a navigation property with eager loading.  This will save you from making three separate DB round trips to the DB to gather up this info.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) MSDN info on how to create the navigation property in code first, model first, and db first.